# Helper method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently learning RoR and I have problem with understanding helper-method's.
This example is from ruby guides.

So, when I click submit form in this example I call `create` method in controller. But, when I click "back" button I go to `index` action.

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %> 
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Back", posts_path %>
```

Why with the same url `posts_path` (this is a helper method, isn't it ?) I have different results?

Comment: The back button in your browser has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails. Is this form on your index page? In that case, you were on the index page, you posted a form, hit "back" in your browser, so you went to page you were on, which was the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP method is different in your case

```
method: POST, posts_path -> create action
method: GET, posts_path -> index action
```

Looking at the result of `rake routes | grep post`  will give you some idea

Answer (score 0):

The redirect uses a GET, while the form uses a POST.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the form submits a `POST` request to `posts_path` while the back button a `GET`. This is the common `REST` way Rails handles its resources. Have a look at the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running) for more info on that